# How to show that two matrices $E_{ij}$ and $ E_{kl}$ are orthogonal unless $(i, j) = (l, k)$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I have encountered the following exercise:

---

We denote by $E_{ij}$ the $n \times n$ matrix given by $E_{ij}(e_j) = e_i$ and $E_{ij}(e_l) = 0$ for $l \neq j$. (Where $(e_1, ..., e_n)$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$)

Show that $E_{ij} \perp E_{kl}$ unless $(i, j) = (l, k)$

---

At first glance, this seemed very simple to me, but for some reason I am stuck. I don't understand why $i$ has to be $= l$, since as long as $j$ is different, you should get zero regardless of what $i$ is, right? Also, I am having difficulties imagining what such a matrix $E_{ij}$ would look like since it seems to me there are many matrices that would fit the above definition.

My through process went into the direction of taking the columns of one of the matrices as vectors and showing that if $j \neq k$, then by definition we get zero. However, the columns of such a matrix don't have to look like one of the basis vectors, so I didn't know how to continue with that idea.

Could someone give me a hint? Or even a full proof?

Answer (score 1):

Your first thought is right.
$E_{ij}E_{kl}=O$ if and only if $j\neq k$

You can denote $E_{ij}$ as $ e_ie_j^{\prime}$ to prove that.